# How do I grab multiple hostname values in regex?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I'm trying to filter out hostname values for templating. Still learning regex and lucene querying..Trying to get multiple subnets on this one (ip is host name).

I'm using Elasticsearch as a datasource

```
Query: {"find": "terms","field":"host.keyword"}

Regex: ip-10-0-8[0-9]|9[0-6]-.*
```

Right now, I'm only getting 80 to 89, need to include 90 to 96 as well.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thx 
Devon

Comment: You need to create a group for the section so that the `|` actually works as you intend. Right now your expression will match `90-x` because the `|` is at the same level as the whole expression. `ip-10-0-8(?:[0-9]|9[0-6])-.*`

Comment: @ctwheels thank you for the reply but it looks like, I'm still only getting the 80s and not the 90s. `ip-10-0-8(?:[0-9]|9[0-6])-.*`

Comment: My bad, I had a typo, put the 8 in the group with the rest `ip-10-0-(?:8[0-9]|9[0-6])-.*`

Comment: I think it should be written as `ip-10-0-(8[0-9]|9[0-6])-.*` to work with Lucene engine.

Comment: @ctwheels works perfectly... Thank you... Wiktor, I get just two digits, not the whole hostname, not sure why..